# "Соединить" 2 роутера на большом расстоянии

Tags: vpn, роутер, ssh-tunnel

У меня есть роутер, например дома, TP-Link, и, например, на даче Mikrotik. Как настроить роутер на даче, чтобы сайты видели мой домашний IP, т.е. что бы я подключался с дачного роутера на домашний и через него уже работал. Прошу подробную инструкцию.

Comment: В простейшем случае - ставьте TeamViewer или RAdmin, или RDP.

Comment: Скорее всего и там, и там, роутеры получают динамические (и, вполне возможно, серые) адреса... так что по-любому нужен внешний статический сервис. *что бы я подключался с дачного роутера на домашний и через него уже работал.* TeamViewer, чего велосипед изобретать-то...